# Create a DATETIME column in SQLite FLutter database?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, flutter, instance

I create a `TABLE` with some columns and everything's ok until I tried to insert a new DATETIME column:

```
_onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.
execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $NAME TEXT, $COLOUR 
TEXT, $BREED TEXT, $BIRTH DATETIME)");
}
```

My Model Class to store is:

```
class Pet {
 int id;
 String name;
 DateTime birth;
 String breed;
 String colour;

 Pet({this.id, this.name, this.birth, this.colour, this.breed});
 }
```

In the controller, I tried to store a new instance of `Pet`, instantiating a new variable `DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();` and saving all in

```
Pet newPet = Pet(
      id: null,
      name: _name,
      colour: _colour,
      breed: _breed,
      birth: _date
  );
```

But when I insert in the database I receive:

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'DateTime'

Comment: Why is `$` prefexied for table names?

Comment: @AnoopThiruonam to avoid hard-coding the table name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are passing `DateTime` object directly.

Use class methods like:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html

or

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/DateTime/toIso8601String.html

You need to pass `String` or `int` instead of an Object. The reason being, you must use supported SQLite data types to store in a SQLite table, find a list of supported data types here https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Also checkout:

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

> DateTime is not a supported SQLite type. Personally I store them as int (millisSinceEpoch) or string (iso8601)

To retrieve your `DateTime` object again:

From Integer:

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(yourValue);
```

From String:

```
DateTime.parse(yourValue);
```

or better way:

```
DateTime.tryParse(yourValue);
```

Comment: If I store dates as int(millsSinceEpoch), can I retrieve based on dates? for example I want to get data based on dates, so select * from tablename ORDER BY date_int;

Comment: Yes @AthiraReddy , DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch() constructor will crate new `DateTime` object from your integer, I edited my answer checkout.