# DART How to map DATETIME into a SQFlite Database

Tags: flutter, datetime, iso8601, sqflite

**Overview:**

App architecture details:

- state management -> [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) (not sure this is relevant, but in case you are interested)
- data storage -> [SQFlite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Specific issue details:

I have a calendarDay data model, with a property of

```
  DateTime date;
```

I know that DateTime is not supported in `SQLite` (not in `SQFlite` either) and [the recommendation](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md) is to use a `String` or `Integer` . I am struggling with how to actually do that.

**Error I am getting:**

*flutter: *** WARNING ***
Invalid argument 2021-07-01 15:09:11.129598 with type DateTime.
Only num, String and Uint8List are supported. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md for details
This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type.*

**This is my setup:**

**calendar_day.dart**

```
 class CalendarDay {
  int? id;
  DateTime date; 

   CalendarDay(
       {this.id,
        required this.date});

    // encode to SQLite database

     Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
     final map = Map<String, dynamic>();
     map['id'] = id;
     map['date'] = date.toIso8601String(); //toString(); this toString did not work //jsonEncode(date) -> SERIALIZE THE ARRAYS INTO JSON strings, this did not work
      return map;
       }

     // decode from SQLite database

       static fromMap(Map map) {
        return CalendarDay(
         id: map['id'],
        date: DateTime.parse(map['date']), // jsonDecode(map['date']));
      }

     }
```

**database_client.dart**

```
   class DatabaseClient {
     Future<Database> initializedDatabase() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
     return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'three_things_database.db'),
       onCreate: (database, version) async {
        
    await database.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE ${Strings.calendarDayDataBase} (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT)",
    ); },
       version: 1, ); }

     // Create / insert calendarDay
      Future<void> insertCalendarDay(CalendarDay day) async {
      final Database database = await initializedDatabase();
      await database.insert(
      Strings.calendarDayDataBase,
      day.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      }
    }
```

I am thinking the problem lies with the toMap() method, since the error notes the DateTime object. But I am a bit stuck and don't really know how to get around this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Additional things I have tried in toMap() :**

I did include the code commented out, but for clarity, I'll post here:

- I tried mapping the DateTime object to a JSONString. This would hopefully be enough for storing the map in SQLite database, but this approach threw the same error.
- Tried mapping to a regular String using date.toString(). This did not work either. Since the recommendation (link above) from the SQFlite folks is to use ISO8601 string, I thought this approach would work.

Related question(s), yet did not solve my question:

- [Create DateTime column in SQFlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165310/create-a-datetime-column-in-sqlite-flutter-database/57165384)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a DATETIME column in SQLite FLutter database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165310/create-a-datetime-column-in-sqlite-flutter-database)

Comment: hi MickaelHrndz, it does not, I am still not able to use the database, and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I did see that question before and I posted it above as related but does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clear example :

```
var dt = DateTime.now();

// String
var dtStr = dt.toIso8601String();
dt = DateTime.tryParse(dtStr);
    
// Int
var dtInt = dt.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(dtInt);
```